# Which is better practice / more performant (using React's setState)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, animation, setstate

I've been testing the performance of animated React components using different methods. The two that seemed most interesting to me were:

- In parent component, keep position of children in state and update using `requestAnimationFrame` then pass props to a bunch of children, which move using `translateX()` for better performance
- maintain position state in each of the children and update its position itself

I saw similar performance between the two. I know that React batches multiple calls to `setState`, but I'm wondering if it still batches the calls among separate components. In the first approach, `setState` is only called once per frame. In the second approach, we call `setState` for each component each frame.

**Which is the better practice?**

Perhaps I'm not using enough child components to see a real difference, but if anyone with more knowledge of React's reconciliation process has any ideas I'd love to know.

Comment: The better practice is to use the code that is simplest/easiest to understand, which I would suspect to be a parent state, passing parameters to children via props.

Comment: This depends on specific case. Is there a need for children or a parent to be aware of children position at any moment? Is there a need to use a child with another parent?

Comment: @MattWay Agreed, though for something potentially more graphic intensive where performance is a concern, would that still be the way to go? My first thought is yes because functional components can be used in place of heavy react components, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @estus The use case is for an animation heavy web application with multiple moving elements. The parent may not need to be aware of a child's position in this case, but I was trying to figure out whether there's a larger performance penalty for each component setting its own state each frame vs a parent component updating child component positions at once.

Comment: This may depend on your app. But it's bad for performance to do this in parent component. You will need to update components that wouldn't be need to be updated otherwise. I guess it's pretty much obvious at this point. I expect that async rendering in React 17 will make the difference even more significant.

Comment: @estus If state is managed properly (no unnecessary passing of irrelevant props or arrow functions changing references) and the children are pure components then ideally that case would be avoided, correct?